# Why the first event "hover" not working?

Tags: jquery, loops, for-loop, hover

The web link: http://oddo.lndemo.taki.com.tw/oddokitchen/maptest.html

When hovering "台北", the image should be changed.
I don't know why the first event "hover" not working.
But the again event "hover" is working.

This is my jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //map hover
    var i   
    for (i = 0; i <= 1; i++) {
        $("#Map area:eq(" + i + ")").bind("hover", {
            id: i
        }, mapFn)
    }

    function mapFn(e) {
        $("#Map area:eq(" + e.data.id + ")").hover(
            function(){
                $(".twmapimg").attr("src","images/th" + e.data.id + ".png");
            },
            function(){
                $(".twmapimg").attr("src","images/twmap.png");
            }
        )
    }
});
```

p.s. The following code is working. Because there are not only one set, I should use  loop "for".

```
$("#Map area:eq(0)").hover(
    function(){

        $(".twmapimg").attr("src","images/th1.png");
    },
    function(){
        $(".twmapimg").attr("src","images/twmap.png");
    }
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery `bind` is an alias for `on()` and `on('hover')` is deprecated.

In addition you can't use `i` in a `for` loop and consume it's value at a later time without using a closure.

At the time the event occurs, `i` will be at it's maximum value.

You can create a closure using `each()` or you could just get the index within the event handler.

Following would replace all the code in the question:

```
$(function(){    
    $('#Map area').hover(function () {
        var index = $(this).index();
        $(".twmapimg").attr("src", "images/th" + index + ".png");
    },function () {
        $(".twmapimg").attr("src", "images/twmap.png");
    });
});
```